# Is the Parse SDK worth it? (cost-effective?)

Tags: ios, security, session, cloud, parse-platform

I'm creating an iOS app that uses remote databases, sessions (login/registration), server side code, and push notifications.

I found this SDK called [Parse](https://www.parse.com/products) that handles all of the server stuff like hosting, the database, cloud code, push notifications, sessions, etc... (so pretty much everything I need to do)

**Is Parse SDK worth using (cost-wise) in general?**

## NOTE - FTR, PARSE HAVE TOTALLY CHANGED THEIR PRICING PLANS (5/2014)

these are the old plans...

- With the [free version](https://www.parse.com/plans), you get 1 million requests a month (I'm guessing this means requests to the database?), 1 million pushes a month, and the burst limit is 20/second.
- The [next version up](https://www.parse.com/plans) costs $199/month, you get 15 million requests a month, 5 million pushes, and the burst limit is 40/second.

Do you think it will pay for itself if goes over 1 million requests / month, and I have to pay for the $199/month version? What if I plan on making money with my app via ads, will it earn enough?

Let's say every person accesses the database 5 times a day, that's 150 times a month, that means it will take 6,666 people until I have to upgrade. On average, will ads pay for the $199/month if I have that many people viewing the ads a day? (also, take into account that Parse is taking care of security, the cost of the servers, and maintenance)

Another thing to consider is, how difficult/costly is it to create (and maintain):

- Server side code
- Database management and security
- Push notifications
- Set up a host
- Session management and security

Will the robustness, security, and ease of maintainability when using Parse will help pay for itself?

Thanks!

Comment: This question is madcap. It's like asking if aircraft make it easy to fly through the air  :O  I pasted in a few anecdotes in the similar answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/23842621/294884

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As someone who has looked into this before, to see if its "worth it" it depends on a few things. And i have a few questions followed by some answers if these are your cases.

**Does your app cost?**
If not then look at how you are going to make the money, will you cover the expenses? I Imagine even with advertising only on a free app you will be making enough money to cover the expenses. If you start to have "too many" requests.. that's a GOOD thing! it means you have a lot of users or active users which in an advertising sense, is good. Or even in a paid app sense.

**Does your app have a bunch of requests operations?** 
For example, in my app we have a chat system, obviously that's going to be a heavy load on requests. Take that into consideration

**Are you in a hurry to develop?**
If your in a hurry, obviously go with Parse, they handle a lot of great things for you and is a really amazing product. fast secure and reliable.

So if you're in a hurry, and are expecting users. Then go for it! Even if you don't get users, you can always go with **Parse Free** and when you reach your limits with Parse Free, you should have enough users to start paying and upgrading your services.

Also, paying for server maintenance is no joke. The only reason we do not use parse, is because of the fact that we like to have control. And even Parse is giving you more and more control each release.

Once Push Notifications have been implemented and are being used, there's really no maintenance after that.

Comment: And what if I wanted to set up my own server? I have an ec2 instance with everything running succcesfully, such as a RESTful api etc. I've been able to send push notifications from test servers provided by the people who wrote push notification tutorials but when I try to copy and paste the push notification code in my own php RESTful server I get an openSSL socket error. I assume that I dont have the right things installed on my server so that it can send notifications. Is there a tutorial or something you could point me to for me to have a look at and finally get it implemented & finalised?

Comment: Pavan, setting up your own server is just no longer possible.  It's ridiculous. There is no "server..." work anymore, there's only the various bAAs.  You might as well be asking "oh, what if I don't want to use iOS or Windows, we're going to write our own desktop OS."  It's history.  There's a very few legacy and out of date clients who still "have their own servers!" and sure, the very largest dotcoms still "make their own bAAs". Why do you think facebook bought parse?

Comment: @Pavan do you have SSL properly established through your Route53 and Load Balancer? I use the same situation your in. As far as what Joe Blow says, using your own system you create is completely if you need it or not. If you need control. Then dont listen to Joe Blow. Also i'll have to re read over my answer again and update it if needed its very old and since my answer Facebook bought them so there different now. Not much but still. As far as your new issue i would just make sure you correctly setup SSL

Comment: @Pavan my appolagies i didnt see you asked that months ago back in Jan, wish i could have helped you then was inactive on Stackoverflow at that time. Hope you got your issue resolved though or hope it helps others.

Comment: @AaronRussell, can we talk? because I definitely dont have the setup you speak of. Its quite intimidating but something I definitely need to get done. perfect timing actually since I need to get it all up and running. I definitely dont have SSL setup correctly on my server at all.

Comment: @JoeBlow the whole reason is cost. I like to save pennies wherever I can and have full control without limitations. There are more reasons, but I've mentioned more than enough.

Comment: @AaronRussell, P.S. I have been able to send push notifications on my server though since then, someone helped me install something that would eliminate the socket error, so my server can now send the notifications properly, but Im not having a few specific questions that I wish to talk to you about, regarding SSL certificates, and sending notifications to specific devices, and appropriate ways to handle them all.

Comment: hi @pavan.  I don't get what you're saying about cost?  **parse is totally free, until you have a LOT of users and traffic.**  regarding is it cheap ONCE YOU HAVE an incredible number of users and you have to pay the tiny amount each month ... yes, it's ridiculously cheap.  **but if you get to the point where you have enough users that you would have to pay parse**, it's the last thing you will be worrying about

Comment: **"Will the robustness, security, and ease of maintainability when using Parse will help pay for itself?"** the answer is like: "You might as well ask if it's worth using an operating system, rather than making one from scratch." Heh!  The cost saving is beyond belief.  Quotes to dot-coms are 100,000, 200,000, $300,000 less if it is a bAAs project, than building-out a whole server side.  Servers are history. You can hire 3 server guys and an app guy for one year, or with a bAAs, just hire the one app guy. Savings are staggering

Comment: @joeblow I'll have to look at why I decided not to go for Parse, there was some sort of limitation which I didnt want, I think it was something along the lines of needing fine tuned control, custom push notifications per user to various different devices and more.

Comment: @Pavan What is it you would like to know? How to add SSL?

Answer (score 10):

In a nutshell, yes. Parse allows developers with little to no infrastructure to execute on an idea without the need to pre-purchase hardware in anticipation of traffic or scale overnight if an idea goes viral.

Another way to look at it is - Would you rather focus on the app/idea or the backend infrastructure along with maintenance? Personally I almost consider the $199 the cost of doing business so to speak and allowing me to focus on implementing new features.

Ads and donations will help make a dent but it's the ease of upgrade where they are most beneficial. Updating your own personal hosting can be anything but easy if your app gains critical mass overnight.

PS - Check out their docs for some quick ways to implement things such as log in pages: [Parse Login and Signup Views](https://www.parse.com/tutorials/login-and-signup-views)

Reference: I've used Parse with some indie projects and in an enterprise setting.

Comment: Again, for anyone googling the whole situation has vastly changed. Latest new here!  http://stackoverflow.com/a/23842621/294884