# Which is better: Parse or AWS

Tags: android, ios, amazon-web-services, parse-platform, backend

I'm working on an ebook store application (my target users will be 10,000 users per months). It's very hard to make up my mind to select the backend between AWS and Parse.

Parse is very simple to use. It could save me one or two months development work. But I'm concerning about the number of requests per month. There are free 1,000,000 requests. But I don't know how they calculate the number of requests. I tested with the demo application. A simple run cost me 4 requests (there seems to be only one request in the code.). I totally have no clue 1,000,000 requests can server how many users.

AWS is free at the first year. It's more flexible. I can control almost everything. The problem is I have to do everything from scratch. Database, Web service, security, server management. Also it's very difficult to estimate the cost.

I'd like to hear your opinions about the cost, performance, scalability, security, etc. Thanks

**Edit at 16th Nov. 2016:**

Parse.com will terminate at 28th Jan. 2017. But it will provide a open source version. I personally think it's even better because I can host our own data at anywhere I like, for example, at AWS.

Comment: i recommended to parse because of nice documentation. easy to implement well demo code, well code description. compare with AWS.

Comment: Actually, Parse has many problems, many small annoying problems which you have to work around. But, of course, it's "utterly amazing", it changes the world.  Choose your bAAs and get to work!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Regarding this very old QA...

- Parse is now closed
- back4app.com is the "new" Parse
- AWS nowadays offers a full suite of such mobile services
- generally, parse (now back4app.com) is much simpler, it is more of an all-in-one, "easy to use" BAAS.  AWS is more industrial, expandable, a little harder to use and set up.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Honestly my main concern is the price. I'm not very familiar with this kind of price plan and not very sure how much it will charge me per month. (I'm not a beginner. I did quite a lot of iOS/android projects including a few client/server app. But I'm just not familiar with AWS, or Baas like Parse.)

Comment: Your comments help me to make up my mind.Thanks.

Comment: AWS now provides mobile services https://aws.amazon.com/mobile/ so this answer is obsolete.

Answer (score 3):

Parse have changed their price plan: you do not have monthly request limit, but burst limit. For free user it's now 30 req/s which is very fair.

For your question, yes, Parse will save you lots of time. I recommend starting with Parse for one reason: if they do not fit to you, you could switch after on AWS (or app engine with cloud endpoint).

Comment: Thanks for your information. I don't know they change the request limit. That's a great news for me.

Comment: Note - even clients who think of their own servers, NOW PROTOTYPE in parse.  it's the only way forward.